# What permissions are required to assign roles to S3 buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a developer working on some services utilizing S3 buckets and wants to be able to assign roles and users to her buckets. I don't really want to give her full IAM rights, but I'm a little unsure which permissions will help set this up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could write an IAM policy to grant her full access to specific S3 buckets you'd like her to control.  You can grant either programmatic access or AWS Management Console access to specific S3 resources.

Example:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::test"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::test/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Also look into creating a [role which can access the specific S3 buckets](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/) in question and then utilizing `iam:PassRole` to enable her to assign this role to other entities.

```
{
    "Sid": "PolicyStatementToAllowUserToPassOneSpecificRole",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [ "iam:PassRole" ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam:::role/My-S3-Role"
}
```